# sum content from looping python

Tags: python, django

i want to write ms.excel file use this script, i get data from this table

```
dataangsuran = Trpinjaman.objects.filter(ckarid=str(id)).select_related('ckarid')
```

then i get data using looping

```
col_num=0
for obj in dataangsuran:
   col = [
      str(obj.ckarid),
      str(obj.ckarid.cnik_nip),
      str(obj.ckarid.tunit),
      str(obj.cangsuranpokok),
    ]
for row_num in xrange(len(col)):
    ws.write(row_pend, col_num, col[row_num])
```

how can i sum from looping data?

```
str(obj.cangsuranpokok)
```

Comment: Do you mean, sum obj.cangsuranpokok value (an int) for every row?

Comment: please explain elaborately what exactly you want to do.

Comment: i want to sum str(obj.cangsuranpokok) @SaurabhGoyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try one of this:

- Sum inside the for loop

  ```
  total = 0
  for obj in dataangsuran:
      total = total + obj.cangsuranpokok
      col = [
        str(obj.ckarid),
        str(obj.ckarid.cnik_nip),
        total,
        str(obj.cangsuranpokok),
      ]
  ```

And then use `total`

- Take the sum from ORM

  ```
  from django.db.models import Sum
  dataangsuran.aggregate(total=Sum('cangsuranpokok'))
  ```

Keep in mind that `dataangsuran` is a `QuerySet` object, so you can add the `aggregate` after the first loop, when you write the excel file.

Comment: do i have to change my django ORM? and change it to dataangsuran.aggregate(total=Sum('cangsuranpokok')) ?

Comment: @Debujang No, you don't need. You can attach aggregate function evene after the first loop. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Gocht, it work now. I change str(obj.ckarid.tunit) to total. Nice